# can I print empty int array withou zero aprearing in java

Tags: java

this is my code can i print my array without zero if it is empty?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.io.*;
public class Stacks{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("what is the size of your stack? :");
        int size = Integer.parseInt (br.readLine());
        int get = size;
        int[] Array = new int[size];
        System.out.println("type: push , pop , exit");
        System.out.println("remember! you can EXIT anytime");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Array));
/*there still a code here but this is just what i needed to show..*/
    }
}
```

please help me.. PS I don't want to import stacks..

Comment: What do you mean by without zero? If your array is empty this will print `[]` not `0`.

Comment: What value do you expect to find in the array?  Each `int` will have *some* value.

Comment: if i input the size of 5 it will print like this [ 0 0 0 0 0]

Comment: can i print it like this? []

Comment: @Hello23, An empty array is one with size 0. It will print out as `[]`. If you have an array of size 5 then it contains 5 ints, which are initialized to 0. It appears intend to treat the array as a stack in the rest of your code, but then what happens if users put `0` on your stack. Do those `0`s need to be printed or not?

Comment: @Linus, yes sir i wanted to create a stack using an array.. that is why if you input zero  i need to display it also.. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just want your array to be displayed without the zeros you can just use a if statement.

```
for( int i = 0; i < Array.length; i ++ ){
    if( Array[i] != 0 ){
        System.out.print( Array[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

This will just iterate through your array and test if the value is zero. If it is not it will display the value, if it is, it disregards it.

Comment: sir if i input zero i also need to display it

Comment: then to answer your question, no you can't print your array as [ ] if it is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Since your not using your Array as an array, but ultimately as a stack, you will not want to use `Arrays.toString()` which is designed for printing arrays as arrays. You need to write your own method, bearing in mind the stack your creating maybe smaller than the size of the array you're populating.

Without knowing how you're stack is implement, a basic model would be

```
public static String arrayAsStack(int[] array, int elements_in_stack) {
   String out = "[";
   for(int i=elements_in_stack-1; i>=0; i--)
      out += arrary[i] + " ";
   out+="]";
   return out;
}
```

This method of course may not be right, depending on the way you format your stack-array. Note the `elements_in_stack` should start at 0. Once you get the right implementation of this method for you stack you can just print the results in the natural way.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using int type i created it using object

```
 import java.util.Arrays;
 import java.io.*;
  public class Stacks{
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("what is the size of your stack? :");
    int size = Integer.parseInt (br.readLine());
    int get = size;
    Object[] Array = new Object[size];
    System.out.println("type: push , pop , exit");
    System.out.println("remember! you can EXIT anytime");
       /* here i use the code of Ryan*/ 
      for( int i = 0; i < Array.length; i ++ ){
         if( Array[i] != null ){
              System.out.print( Array[i] + " ");
             }
        }
 /*there still a code here but this is just what i needed to show..*/
   }
}
```

now i can display 0 if I input it..